# Why does my validation loss go so high after few epochs?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification, computer-vision

I am facing an issue with my pretrained mobilenetv3 model, it is quite strange how the validation loss is behaving, it starts low but then goes up ridiculously high. I have normalized my images as well and I am using TF with Keras.

```
25/25 [==============================] - 68s 2s/step - loss: 0.5515 - accuracy: 0.9213 - val_loss: 0.0361 - val_accuracy: 0.9898
Epoch 2/50
25/25 [==============================] - 57s 2s/step - loss: 0.0490 - accuracy: 0.9797 - val_loss: 0.2195 - val_accuracy: 0.9746
Epoch 3/50
25/25 [==============================] - 62s 2s/step - loss: 0.0315 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.7404 - val_accuracy: 0.9898
Epoch 4/50
25/25 [==============================] - 57s 2s/step - loss: 0.0093 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 1.6772 - val_accuracy: 0.9797
Epoch 5/50
25/25 [==============================] - 56s 2s/step - loss: 0.0124 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 1.5263 - val_accuracy: 0.9898
Epoch 6/50
25/25 [==============================] - 57s 2s/step - loss: 0.0303 - accuracy: 0.9937 - val_loss: 24.9216 - val_accuracy: 0.9137
Epoch 7/50
25/25 [==============================] - 59s 2s/step - loss: 0.0056 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 281.5234 - val_accuracy: 0.7157
Epoch 8/50
25/25 [==============================] - 55s 2s/step - loss: 0.0042 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 93.2665 - val_accuracy: 0.8274
Epoch 9/50
25/25 [==============================] - 57s 2s/step - loss: 0.0051 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 50.2444 - val_accuracy: 0.8832
Epoch 10/50
25/25 [==============================] - 62s 2s/step - loss: 4.7321e-04 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 90.5489 - val_accuracy: 0.8528
Epoch 11/50
25/25 [==============================] - 57s 2s/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 73.0347 - val_accuracy: 0.8528
```

My code:

```
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
EPOCHS = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_CLASSES = 2
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
DATA_DIR = "real_data/"

# Load the dataset
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATA_DIR,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=42,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATA_DIR,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=42,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
)
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (preprocess_input(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (preprocess_input(x), y))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Large(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), include_top=True, weights="imagenet")
base_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
base_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

Comment: This looks like overfitting. It seems that before starting to overfit, your model achieves good numbers, so you can simply use early stopping.

Comment: But isn't it strange that the model achieves 90+ accuracy in the first first epoch? Also, i have 987 images, could that cause an issue for overfitting?

Comment: 987 certainly are very few. The validation accuracy reaches a very high number, though. If the problem is not imbalanced, I don't see a problem from the information you provided.